How to know the IP address of my webcam?
My laptop has a webcam and I want to know its IP address so I can access it remotely with ngrok.
What I want to do is exactly like this:
https://www.digitaltrends.com/home/how-to-view-your-ip-camera-remotely-via-a-web-browser/
I can't find info online for such a task.
Any help will be appreciated.
--------------EDIT-------------:
The question in this link How to check available webcams from the command line? answers a part of the question: i.e knowing the address of the internal camera.
But it doesn't answer "how to get its IP or at least derive its value from another command".
i.e, say I have the python code:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("cam_ip_here")

What I want to do, is generate a link with "ngrok", and via it access the IP of the internal camera, thus exposing the local webcam to the internet.

This question is similar to: How to check available webcams from the command line?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why do you assume it has an IP address?

@mikewhatever answered it: the local webcam in the laptop has no IP to start with; unless a lengthy process is done.
https://www.quora.com/Can-I-access-a-webcam-just-by-knowing-an-IP-address
Big disappointment.
